# Objects Behind Safety Net/Cage Thrown Forward at Highway Speed

Tags: physics

I contacted the University of British Columbia Mathematics Department regarding this, and they directed me to post my question here.

We are trying to improve the safety of equipment storage in our vehicles.

---

SCENARIO A
Inside a vehicle, there are D-Rings securely bolted into the metal frame of the vehicle.
Maximum weight D-Rings can withstand in a pull test = 400 lbs or 181.44 kg

Clipped to the D-Rings are Metal Snaps
Maximum weight Metal Snaps can withstand in a pull test = 485 lbs or 220 kg

Sewn onto the Metal Snaps is a net made out of polypropylene.
Net Tensile strength = 800 lbs
Net Web Lifting Net Test = 200 lbs
Net Thread Pull-Test = 11,000 lbs

If the vehicle has equipment behind the Net secured by the Metal Snaps and the D-Rings, is travelling at 120 km/h or 75 mph, and comes to a VERY sudden stop so that the equipment is thrown forward with momentum force, what is the maximum weight / mass the Net can withstand?

---

SCENARIO B
Inside a vehicle, there is a metal cage securely bolted to a heavy plywood subfloor that sits upon the vehicle floor.

The maximum weight this cage can stop is reported by the manufacturer to be 114 kg or 250 lbs

If the vehicle has equipment behind the Metal Cage, is travelling at 120 km/h or 75 mph, and comes to a VERY sudden stop, so that the equipment is thrown forward with momentum force, what is the maximum weight / mass the Cage can withstand?

Comment: You might also try asking at physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question cannot be answered without a quantitative definition of "sudden stop".  Assuming you stop under driver's control (as opposed to hitting a concrete wall), it would be useful to know the vehicle's stopping distance from some speed under optimum conditions (new tires, dry road, etc...)